# Ubuntu 18.04 stuck on startup

Tags: 18.04, startup

I'm fairly new to Ubuntu and Linux in general. When I tried to start Ubuntu today I got this screen:

[image: this screen].

I've tried looking up solutions, but all the ones I found were related to startup being stuck on the splash. Any ideas/suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you access recovery mode?